# How to make Gradle build system-environment-independent?

Tags: java, build, gradle

I recently configured a Gradle build, but it turned out that it works differently on different machines: in particular, it did build on my machine and didn't on my colleague's. We identified the Java version to be the cause, as I used 1.7 and he used 1.8. The question, in general, is how to make the Gradle build totally environment-independent, to be sure that it builds exactly the same way, regardless of various versions of software installed, locales, encodings, and so on. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use docker to provide unified development environment.

Comment: Typically you specify different build instructions for all the environment configurations you want to support, but there's no way to make a truly universal build. The closest you can come is to support many different combinations.

Comment: Continuing the last comment, there's no way to make a build entirely portable.  You wouldn't expect your Java application to build on a CICS mainframe. You have to expect your build to have some prerequisites. If you require Java 7, then specify that.  However, it should be possible to configure a Gradle build to behave slightly different for Java 7 vs. Java 8, as long as you understand the different needs of those JDKs.

Comment: i have same problem running script on linux, creates totally different structure than on windows :(